# Non-vanishing winding number for the interior points of a Jordan curve.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology

According to the [Jordan Curve Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) if $\gamma : [0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ is a simple closed curve, then $\mathbb R^2\!\smallsetminus\!\gamma([0,1])$  consists of exactly two connected components. One of these components is bounded (the interior) and the other is unbounded (the exterior), and the curve $\gamma$ is the boundary of each component.

Let $U$ be the bounded component of $\mathbb R^2\!\smallsetminus\!\gamma([0,1])$ and $P$ a point in $U$. I can not prove the following (intuitively obvious):

*The simple closed curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to \mathbb R^2\!\smallsetminus\!\{P\}$ is not null homotopic.*

I imagine that it suffices to show that the winding number of $\gamma$ around every point $P\in U$ is $\pm 1$. But I can not prove even that.

**EDIT.** Is there a way to avoid using Schoenflies Theorem?

Comment: If you're familiar with the Schoenflies theorem, that reduces this problem to the trivial case where $\gamma$ bounds an embedded disk. Otherwise, try extending a null-homotopy of $\gamma$ across $\mathbb{R}^2$. (This is nontrivial, but there are a lot of results about isotopies on $S^2$. Alternatively, you can use various approximations to assume that the null-homotopy is nice, the note that the winding number is invariant under small perturbations.)

Comment: There's a nice proof of this in the Guillemin and Pollack textbook.  Winding numbers aren't the most convenient technique for the proof, intersection theory is a little more pleasant to work with.

Comment: There's a proof on pages 219-222 of A. F. Beardon, *Complex Analysis* (1979). Although I haven't read that far in the book, I can see there's no mention of Schoenflies in the index (no pun intended), which is encouraging. Certainly the reader is not presumed to know any algebraic topology. (It's an introductory textbook.)